# Bing Map pushpins not displaying on an Office365 SharePoint page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, bing-maps

I have an Office 365 SharePoint site where I am trying to display data from a list that contains geolocation data using the Bing Maps ajax control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx). My map is loading up correctly and displaying the correct location but the actual pushpins are not displaying. I've tried default and custom pushpin icons to no avail. When I use similar JavaScript on a 'vanilla' html page, the pushpins display just fine so I think there must be some sort of conflict with the SharePoint JavaScript or css.

Here the relevant block of code:

```
function fillListData(web, list, items) {
    var tile = $("#" + tileId);
    var content = tile.find('.tileContent');
    var mapOptions = {
            credentials: "",
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.auto,
            showDashboard: false
            };

    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(content[0], mapOptions);
    var locs = [];

    var e = items.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {

        var listItem = e.get_current();
        var title = listItem.get_item("Title");
        var loc = listItem.get_item("Location");
        var lat = loc.get_latitude();
        var lon = loc.get_longitude();

        var mapLoc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon);

        locs.push(mapLoc);
        //var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(mapLoc, {text: title, visible: true, icon:'../Style Library/Images/flag_red.png'}); 
        //var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(mapLoc, {visible: true, icon:'../Style Library/Images/flag_red.png', width: 50, height: 50}); 
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(mapLoc); 
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }

    var bestView = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);
    map.setView({bounds:bestView });

}
```

Any insights are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the lat and lon values. Make sure they actually have a value and that it is a number and not a string. If it is a string use parseFloat to convert it to a number. Numbers that are stored as a string is a fairly common cause for pushpins not displaying as the Location class ends up being invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else comes across this problem, going into your internet settings, lowering protection levels and going into "Custom Levels", finding "Enable mixed content" and enabling that has been the solution for two machines here.